# Fill input automatically when selecting a value in select

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that creates a select and an input, and returns the data to a select with a query to the database.

```
const campos_max = 10;

let x = 0;
$('#add_field').click (function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); 
if (x < campos_max) {
    $('#listas').append(`<select class="form-control1 Reff${x}" name="Ref[]"><option></option></select><input type="text" class="form-control1 Desigg${x}" name="Designacao[]" id="Desigg" value="" required>`}

$.ajax({
    url: "artigo1.php",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(result){
    
    var html = $(`.Reff${x}`);

    result.forEach(element => {
     html.append(`<option value="`+element+`">`+element+`</option>`);
    });

    x++;

    }
});
});
```

Now I intend that when selecting the value in the select that it automatically fills the input with the value also returned from the query to the database.

I'm trying this way:

```
$(`.Reff${x}`).change(function(){ 
        var Refart = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"artigo.php",
            dataType:"Json",
            data:{Refart:Refart},
            success:function(callback){
                
             var data_array = callback;          
             artigo1 = data_array

              $(`.Desigg${x}`).html(artigo1);
              document.getElementById('Desigg').value = artigo1;

            }
     });    
    });
```

When I select the first select, it automatically fills in the input.
The problem is when I add the second select the input, when selecting the value of the second select, it changes the value of the first input and does not fill the input according to the select.

Comment: You are always changing the value of the element with the ID `Desigg` which has to be unique. You dynamically add more inputs with the same ID but `document.getElementById('Desigg').value = artigo1;` will always refer to the first element. You could alternatively use `getElementsByClassName('desig-input')` instead and add the class `desig-input` to the input.

Comment: @SaschaM78 But if you add the class `desig-input` when I select the value in select it does not return the value in the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your select-box is generated dynamically first bind it with static element i.e : `any div,document,body..etc` .Then you can give some other div to your select-box and inputs so whenever select value is change you just need to use `closest` and `find` to add the value return from ajax to required inputs.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
const campos_max = 10;

let x = 0;
$('#add_field').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (x < campos_max) {
    //added outer div here
    $('#listas').append(`<div><select class="form-control1 Reff${x}" name="Ref[]"><option></option></select><input type="text" class="form-control1 Desigg${x}" name="Designacao[]" id="Desigg" value="" required></div>`)
  }

  /*$.ajax({
    url: "artigo1.php",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(result) {*/

  var html = $(`.Reff${x}`);

  /* result.forEach(element => {*/
  //demo datas
  html.append(`<option value="A">A</option><option value="B">B</option><option value="C">C</option>`);
  /* });*/

  x++;

  /* }
        });*/
});
//for handling dynamic slectsboxs
$(document).on("change", "select[class*=Reff]", function() {
  var Refart = $(this).val();
  var selector = $(this) //get cuurent reference 
  console.log(Refart)
  /*$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "artigo.php",
    dataType: "Json",
    data: {
      Refart: Refart
    },
    success: function(callback) {

  var data_array = callback;
  artigo1 = data_array*/

  artigo1 = "soemthing..."
  selector.closest("div").find("input").val(artigo1) //get closest div find input add value there..

  /* }
      });*/
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="listas"></div>
<button id="add_field">Add more</button>
```

Comment: I am unable to apply your example. I'll add to the question how did my code look with the example I left to see what I'm doing wrong. Can be?

Comment: Hi change `selector.closest(".desig-input").find(".desig-input1").val(artigo1)` to `selector.closest(".teste").find(".desig-input1").val(artigo1)` you need to get the outer div where your both `select` and `input` are i.e `teste` then use `.find`